# Any plans for a dedicated Ask Ubuntu Android app?

Tags: discussion, android

I was wondering if there are any plans to release a dedicated Ask Ubuntu app on Android.

I know of a few stack exchange apps but with the upcoming Ubuntu for Android will a Ask Ubuntu app follow?

I think me and many others would gladly download this and even pay a pound or so for it.

Comment: What's wrong with the various un-dedicated Stack Exchange apps floating around? Eg StackAnywhere

Comment: Nothing I am just curious as I only use this site on stack exchange and this would be a good companion for Ubuntu on Android.

Comment: The mobile version of this site looks great and works perfectly. Many of us would never install a dedicated app just to browse a single website, even though this seems to be a trend lately.